# iOS Siri kit integration - invoke the app and send the custom instruction

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sirikit

Here is my detailed description to achieve by using Siri.

I'm new in Siri kit integration. I have an app  which has certain functionalities like send some information to server. The input is number.  Below mentioned actions I want to do via Siri :

- Instruct to Siri - Send *MyAppname* amount used
- Siri asks -  what is the amount.
- Instruct to Siri - Submit

Go through Apple doc and some of other blogs but I didn't find any solution as per my requirements.
 1.https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/SiriDomains.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016875-CH9-SW2

2.http://jamesonquave.com/blog/adding-siri-to-ios-10-apps-in-swift-tutorial/

Do we have any custom Intent to perform this?

Is there any way to achieve this actions
Please let me your ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use the intents from the available domains. If you want to send money or something similar to another user use the INSendPaymentIntent intent.